# Does accessing type of a lazy val cause it to be evaluated?

Tags: scala, types, lazy-evaluation

As the question title states, does accessing `type` of a `lazy val` member result in evaluation of that member? Or does it simply use its static type?

Here is an example code in which I have an `implicit lazy val`, and I would like to use its type in the method that accept an `implicit val` with that type:

> `implicit lazy val nonSpaces: Array[(Point, Part)]`

...

> `def randomNonSpaceCoordinate(implicit nonSpaces: this.nonSpaces.type): Point =
>       nonSpaces(Utils.Random.randUpTo(nonSpaces.length))._1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's check it out:

```
scala> object Test {
     |   lazy val test: String = {println("bang!"); "value"}
     |   val p: this.test.type = null
     |   def testDef(p: this.test.type) = println(p)
     | }
defined module Test

scala> Test.testDef(Test.p)
null

scala> Test.testDef(Test.test)
bang!
value
```

So as you can see just accessing the type does not require the lazy val to be actually evaluated.

Comment: I got my answer thanks. I think I was being lazy, since I could have tried too. But it is nice to have this as QA in StackOverflow, right?

So just accessing the type does not require the lazy val to be actually evaluated. Could you edit your answer to include this statement?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

No. Type-level computations (apart from their shadow selves "reflection") are a compile-time thing.

You can verify things like this:

```
scala> lazy val lv1 = { println("Initializing lv1"); "lv1" }
lv1: String = <lazy>

scala> def m1(s: lv1.type): Int = s.length
m1: (s: lv1.type)Int

scala> lv1
Initializing lv1
res5: String = lv1
```

However, you may want to think more carefully about using `.type` like this, since it's a so-called **path-depedent type** and in a case like this it's probably too narrow to be useful:

```
scala> m1(lv1)
res6: Int = 3

scala> m1("42")
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("42")
 required: lv1.type
              m1("42")
```

In your case, you will only be able to call `randomNonSpaceCoordinate` with `nonSpaces`, making it a little pointless to pass it as an argument at all.

Comment: I didn't understand why second call to m1 is failed, isn't lv1.type alread String? How can it be more specific? It seems `type` is not what I understood it to be. What would you suggest? I would like to have the same type as my implicit val as the parameter, because I will have local val alternatives. For example, is it OK if I declare them with the same type expression as the implicit val?

Comment: That's my point. It's the `String` that is the type of `nonSpaces` _specifically_ and of no other `String`. Hence the term "path-dependent type."

Comment: Ah, ok. So that's really not of much use in my case. And I will have to look into path-dependent type topic. Currently I don't know which answer to mark as "the answer" because both are correct, this one is a specific and a useful answer to my problem; on the other hand @senia 's is a direct answer to the question with an example. :) Any suggestions?